# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginasweb\alto remate\conexion.php on line 3

Tags: php, html

Me salta el siguiente error y no se como resolverlo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega tu código como texto y no como imagen pues asi es difícil leerlo

Comment: A la línea 3, al final de la línea quita )); y añade solo );

Answer (score 1):

EN la linea 3 estas cerrando con doble paréntesis al final y es con uno osea

```
... or die("<h2>No se encuentra el servidor</h2>");
```

Comment: ahora me salta el siguiente error: 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'gabriel'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginasweb\alto remate\conexion.php on line 3
No se encuentra el servidor

Comment: El usuario no tiene todos los privilegios, o los datos que estas pasando en tu conexión son erróneos, proba con ...mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','usuarios')

Answer (score 0):

amigo si te dice que la base de datos no se encuentra es de imaginar que el MySQL no esta dentro de tu alojamiento de MYSQL debe estar afuera si lo tienes en un VPS p servidor dedicado externo revisa que tengas el puerto abierto y la IP apuntando bien al VPS o server dedicado. tambien revisa el usuario es el que tienes creado se visualiza aqui mira:

[image: se ve en privilegios]

Comment: esta activado todos los privilegios